# 'merging' 2 files into a third using perl

Tags: perl, file-io

I am reviewing for a test and I can't seem to get this example to code out right.

**Problem: Write a perl script, called ileaf, which will linterleave the lines of a file with those of another file writing the result to a third file. If the files are a different length then the excess lines are written at the end.**

**A sample invocation:
ileaf file1 file2 outfile**

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open(file1, "$ARGV[0]");
open(file2, "$ARGV[1]");
open(file3, ">$ARGV[2]");

while(($line1 = <file1>)||($line2 = <file2>)){
    if($line1){
            print $line1;
    }

    if($line2){
            print $line2;
    }
}
```

This sends the information to screen so I can immediately see the result.  The final verson should "print file3 $line1;"  I am getting all of file1 then all of file2 w/out and interleaving of the lines.

If I understand correctly, this is a function of the use of the "||" in my while loop.  The while checks the first comparison and if it's true drops into the loop.  Which will only check file1.  Once file1 is false then the while checks file2 and again drops into the loop.

What can I do to interleave the lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not getting what you want from `while(($line1 = <file1>)||($line2 = <file2>)){` because as long as `($line1 = <file1>)` is true, `($line2 = <file2>)` never happens.

Try something like this instead:

```
open my $file1, "<", $ARGV[0] or die;
open my $file2, "<", $ARGV[1] or die;
open my $file3, ">", $ARGV[2] or die;

while (my $f1 = readline ($file1)) {
  print $file3 $f1;  #line from file1

  if (my $f2 = readline ($file2)) {  #if there are any lines left in file2
    print $file3 $f2;
  }
}

while (my $f2 = readline ($file2)) {   #if there are any lines left in file2
  print $file3 $f2;
}

close $file1;
close $file2;
close $file3;
```

Comment: That is working.  I think I was trying to combine too many steps into one loop. Thanks Tim.

Comment: Of course, `readline($file1)` is much more commonly written as `<$file1>`. It's also much more common to print to STDOUT and simply redirect the output to a file if desired (because it's far more flexible).

Answer (score 2):

You'd think if they're teaching you Perl, they'd use the modern Perl syntax. Please don't take this personally. After all, this is how you were taught. However, you should know the new Perl programming style because it helps eliminates all sorts of programming mistakes, and makes your code easier to understand.

- **Use the pragmas `use strict;` and `use warnings;`**. The warnings pragma replaces the need for the `-w` flag on the command line. It's actually more flexible and better. For example, I can turn off particular warnings when I know they'll be an issue. The `use strict;` pragma requires me to declare my variables with either a *my* or *our*. (NOTE: Don't declare Perl built in variables). 99% of the time, you'll use *my*. These variables are called *lexically scoped*, but you can think of them as true local variables. Lexically scoped variables don't have any value outside of their scope. For example, if you declare a variable using `my` inside a while loop, that variable will disappear once the loop exits.
- **Use the three parameter syntax for the `open` statement**:  In the example below, I use the three parameter syntax. This way, if a file is called `>myfile`, I'll be able to read from it.
- **Use locally defined file handles. Note that I use `my $file_1_fh` instead of simply FILE_1_HANDLE. The old way, FILE_1_HANDLE is globally scoped, plus it's very difficult to pass the file handle to a function. Using lexically scoped file handles just works better.
- **Use `or` and `and` instead of `||` and `&&`**: They're easier to understand, and their operator precedence is better. They're more likely not to cause problems.
- **Always check whether your `open` statement worked**: You need to make sure your `open` statement actually opened a file. Or use the `use autodie;` pragma which will kill your program if the `open` statements fail (which is probably what you want to do anyway.

And, here's your program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $file_1, "<", shift;
open my $file_2, "<", shift;
open my $output_fh, ">", shift;

for (;;) {
    my $line_1 = <$file_1>;
    my $line_2 = <$file_2>;
    last if not defined $line_1 and not defined $line_2;
    no warnings qw(uninitialized);
    print {$output_fh} $line_1 . $line_2;
    use warnings;
}
```

In the above example, I read from both files *even if they're empty*. If there's nothing to read, then `$line_1` or `$line_2` is simply undefined. After I do my read, I check whether both `$line_1` and `$line_2` are undefined. If so, I use `last` to end my loop.

Because my file handle is a scalar variable, I like putting it in curly braces, so people know it's a file handle and not a variable I want to print out. I don't need it, but it improves clarity.

Notice the `no warnings qw(uninitialized);`. This turns off the uninitialized warning I'll get. I know that either `$line_1` or `$line_3` might be uninitialized, so I don't want the warning. I turn it back on right below my print statement because it is a valuable warning.

Here's another way to do that `for` loop:

```
while ( 1 ) {
    my $line_1 = <$file_1>;
    my $line_2 = <$file_2>;
    last if not defined $line_1 and not defined $line_2;
    print {$output_fh} $line_1 if defined $line_1;
    print {$output_fh} $line_2 if defined $line_2;
}
```

The *infinite loop* is a while loop instead of a *for* loop. Some people don't like the C style of `for` loop and have banned it from their coding practices. Thus, if you have an *infinite loop*, you use `while ( 1 ) {`. To me, maybe because I came from a C background, `for (;;) {` means *infinite loop*, and `while ( 1 ) {` takes a few extra milliseconds to digest.

Also, I check whether `$line_1` or `$line_2` is defined before I print them out. I guess it's better than using `no warning` and `warning`, but I need two separate print statements instead of combining them into one.

Comment: In this particular case, I would argue that `||` rather than `or` is the correct choice. My general rule of thumb is `||` for logical operations (`if ($a || $b)`) and `or` for flow control (`open or die`), because the expectations that way tend to match the operator precedence rules.

Comment: I guess it's a style preference. The main thing is that the order of precedence is lower with `or` and `and` and usually works out better when you don't parenthesize. As an old C programmer, I too thought `||` and `&&` look better in logic, but if you're suppose to downplay the C Style for loop, I guess the other C stuff should be deprecated too. .

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option that uses [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm)'s `zip` to interleave arrays and [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm) to read and write files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw/zip/;
use File::Slurp qw/read_file write_file/;

chomp( my @file1 = read_file shift );
chomp( my @file2 = read_file shift );

write_file shift, join "\n", grep defined $_, zip @file1, @file2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed Tim A has a nice solution already posted.  This solution is a bit wordier, but might illustrate exactly what is going on a bit more.

The method I went with reads all of the lines from both files into two arrays, then loops through them using a counter.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open(IN1, "<", $ARGV[0]);
open(IN2, "<", $ARGV[1]);

my @file1_lines;
my @file2_lines;

while (<IN1>) {
    push (@file1_lines, $_);
}
close IN1;
while (<IN2>) {
    push (@file2_lines, $_);
}
close IN2;

my $file1_items = @file1_lines;
my $file2_items = @file2_lines;

open(OUT, ">", $ARGV[2]);
my $i = 0;
while (($i < $file1_items) || ($i < $file2_items)) {
    if (defined($file1_lines[$i])) {
        print OUT $file1_lines[$i];
    }
    if (defined($file2_lines[$i])) {
        print OUT $file2_lines[$i];
    }
    $i++
}
close OUT;
```